# Solving $|x|^{(x-2)(x+1)}\lt 1$

Tags: proof-verification, inequality, absolute-value

I'm supposed to find the solution set of the inequality $|x|^{(x-2)(x+1)}\lt 1$. Here's my attempt. I seem to be getting a different solution than suggested by the graph of $f(x)=|x|^{(x-2)(x+1)}-1$.

**My Attempt**

$$\begin{aligned}x\gt 1 \implies  &(x-2)(x+1)\log x\lt0 \\ &(x-2)(x+1)\lt0\\ &x\in (-1,2) \cap (1,\infty)=\boxed{(1,2)}\end{aligned}$$

---

$$\begin{aligned}x\in(0,1)\implies &(x-2)(x+1)\log x\gt 0\\&(x-2)(x+1)\lt 0\\&x\in(-1,2)\cap (0,1)=\boxed{(0,1)}\end{aligned}$$

Similarly I made cases for $x\lt-1$ and $x\in (-1,0)$ both of whose solution sets came out to be the empty set. Now for the solution set we must take the union of the individual solution sets doing which gives us that $x\in(0,1)\cup (1,2)$. Whereas the solution is $(1,2)$.

Can you please spot the mistake? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually for $|x| < 1$ it should be $(x-2)(x+1)\log |x| < 0$ as before, which implies the strict inequality $(x-2)(x+1) >0$ must be positive [and for $x=0$ it is necessary and sufficient for $(x-2)(x+1) >0$ at $x=0$]. This gives $|x| < 1 \Rightarrow x \in (-1,0)$

Comment: But are we not supposed to change the sign if the base is $\lt 1$ in magnitude?

Comment: The sign of $\log z$ changes to a negative value for $|z| < 1$; for $|z| < 1$ you want $(x-2)(x+1) > 0$, as $\log |z|$ is negative

Comment: No while taking $\log()$ on both sides, whenever the base is less than $1$ we change signs and since the $\log x$ was also present which itself is negative for $x\in(0,1)$ the sign changes again. This was what I thought.

Comment: That is not correct though. You "change signs" to go convert $\log x$ to $\log \frac{1}{x}$ for any positive real value of $x$.

Comment: So whenever we change signs seeing the base less than $1$ we're already accounting for the sign of the $\log(x)$ that is left in.

Comment: I am not positive what you mean here. Iff $A < B$ then $\log A < \log B$ for all positive values of $A$ and $B$. Iff $1 <$ $|x|^{f(x)}$ then $0 < f(x)\log |x|$. Even if $|x| < 1$.

Comment: I mean if $a^{f(x)}\gt a^{g(x)}$ such that $a\lt 1$ then $f(x)\lt g(x)$.

Comment: Well yes. Work this through: $a^{f(x)} > a^{g(x)} \Rightarrow (\log a)f(x) > (\log a)g(x)$, whether $\log a$ is positive or negative. However, Iff $\log a <0$ then this  implies $f(x) < g(x)$.

Comment: Got it. So basically I accounted for this sign change twice. Thanks